# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat

Tags: node-sass

I am having trouble transpiling an `.scss` file from one directory to another in `.css`. All of my folder hierarchies are the same and should not give this file location problem.

```
$ node-sass -w -r -i /build/scss/pages/index.scss /dist/css/index.min.css --output-style compressed
An output directory must be specified when compiling a directory
An output directory must be specified when compiling a directory
fs.js:114
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/build/scss/pages/index.scss'
    at Object.lstatSync (fs.js:840:3)
    at Object.module.exports.parseDir (C:\Users\thiag\Documents\PROJETOS\instagram-clone\node_modules\sass-graph\sass-graph.js:153:10)
    at Object.watcher.reset (C:\Users\thiag\Documents\PROJETOS\instagram-clone\node_modules\node-sass\lib\watcher.js:17:21)
    at watch (C:\Users\thiag\Documents\PROJETOS\instagram-clone\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass:260:20)
    at run (C:\Users\thiag\Documents\PROJETOS\instagram-clone\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass:319:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\thiag\Documents\PROJETOS\instagram-clone\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass:405:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The folder directories by copying the path in the visual code studio are as follows:

```
build --> root
dist --> root
package.json --> root

build\scss\pages\_index.scss
dist\css
```

Answer (score 3):

**The problem that was occurring was the following:**

`SASS` does not read an **"underline"** file, such as `_index.scss`. So to solve the problem I removed the **"underline"**.

Another way is to create a file such as `.scss` file and another such as `_arquivo2.scss`. The `.scss` file will contain the `@import` of `_file2.scss`!